# Cannot get php to work on ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I recently created a server with a digital ocean and I have been trying to learn their commands and what not so I can create web servers. I have a project that I have uploaded, and when I visited that page, what was meant to show my project, displays as a blank webpage

I have located the problem to this file, see I have wrote a bunch of test 1, test 2 to find my problem because no errors are showing. Go to line 45 and you will see this, and then at line 111 where it is throwing an exception is where it halts.

https://bitbucket.org/benshepherd/ben-mvc/src/79041e868b85aeeacfefac23ce729a0c2a6b949f/Libs/Controller.php?at=master

you can see here `http://178.62.26.90/mvc/` the results of what it is echoing out.

Comment: It's throwing the exception because the file is not found

Comment: "can't get php to work" means PHP isn't working AT ALL. You should be saying "my code has syntax errors". That's not php's problem, that's YOUR problem.

Comment: It works fine on localhost, no problem. As soon as I upload it to the server, it whacks out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 97: Either the model class needs to be called pagesModel or this line needs to change to be

```
$class = ucfirst( $modelName ).'Model';
```

Also line 94:

```
$file = __DIR__.'/Models/'.$modelName.'.php';
```

Should probably be:

```
$file = __DIR__.'/../Models/'.$modelName.'.php';
```

Comment: Thanks. It was because the file was looking for Model/pages.php instead of Model/Pages.php